# Filter not in Python

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am having a list

```
customers=Customers.objects.filter(limit=1)

level1=customers.filter(status=1)

level2=customers.filter(status=2)
```

I want to populate a third list which must have name of all customers that are in `customers` but not in `level1` and `level2`

I have tried this much

```
returned=customers.filter(~level1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude):

```
Customers.objects.exclude(status__in=[1,2])
```

or

```
Customers.objects.filter(whatever=whatever).exclude(status__in=[1,2])
```